# Edit view open point to a content type

Tags: 2013, content-type, custom-list, edit-form

I have a custom list with two content types.  When I click the edit button for the item it opens into content type #1.   How do I have it open into the content type #2 form when I select the edit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While adding it which content type you have selected same content type will be displayed while editing.
If you want to change the view to the another content type then you have to change the content type of the item, so that item view will also be edited.
Or if you want to have content type #2 for all the item while adding and editing then you have to set it as default or create items with this content type.

Note :- If you use visual studio solution to create that list, then you can change the edit form layout to get show the details of content type 2 for editing and set content type 1 as default list content type. so that on creating new item it will take content type 1 and while editing it will take content type 2.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set the desired Content Type as a default content type for your List.

Go to List Settings from ribbon and select the link shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Change Content Type order in a List]

And then you can change the position of the Content Type as shown in the another screenshot below.
[image: Change position from the top]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is for adding new item content type will be selected but question is for editing right? i guess he has to change the content type.?